# which properties are available in fb graph object?

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I want to use fb SDK to get social data after user logs in to my android app.

For example: gender, age, education, address, sexual orientation, pages he\she likes and more.

I have thought using this:

```
com.facebook.model.GraphObject.getProperty(String propertyName)
```

but couldn't find documentation of available names properties.
How would you get the info I asked above?

**update**

I have tried using [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/#fields) documentation as @Tobi suggested

but my code return bday == null

even though i have bday in my fb account

```
    Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
            if (response.getError() == null && user != null) {
                String fbId = null;
                try {
                    Log.i(TAG, "User ID " + user.getId());
                    Log.i(TAG, "Email " + user.asMap().get("email"));

                    String bday = (String) user.getProperty("birthday");
```

Comment: Have a look at the official documentation of the User here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/#fields

Comment: As https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/interface/GraphUser/#getBirthday suggests, you should use user.getBirthday()